# Использование ffmpeg для захвата кадра с веб-камеры на C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, web-camera

Нужно получить кадр с камеры на C++ и кодировать его в base64 (это для браузеров). Вроде весь нужный функционал есть в ffmpeg, но мануалов как-то мало.

Кто разрабатывал с помощью ffmpeg, можете продемонстрировать минимальный пример кода для захвата кадра с вебки? Получить идентификатор устройства -> запустить съёмку с заданным разрешением -> зафиксировать кадр в буфере. Хотя бы просто функции.

Comment: а какой протокол обмена данными в веб-камере?

Comment: То есть протокол в веб-камере? В среде Windows нужно получить доступ к камере (vfw не подходит, так как выводится диалог выбора камеры, а directshow не подходит, так как компилятор MinGW не имеет некоторых заголовков directx). Сетевая часть должна передавать Base64 по HTTP/HTTPS

Comment: я с вебками не работал по этому и спрашиваю. а вообще любые устройства имеют свои протоколы обмена данными. например ip камеры передают данные в формате прокола rtsp. просто нужно узнать какой какой протокол используют веб камеры и от этого уже отталкиваться. я так понимаю веб камера постоянно транслирует видеопоток на каком то протоколе. нужно узнать куда этот поток направлен и оттуда вынимать кадры. думаю у нее нет никакой записи а прямая трансляция вместо этого.